# TensorFlow(GPU) uses GPU but seems not use CUDA to accelerate, what's wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running tensorflow on Ubuntu16 with a single gpu. I believe it utilizes gpu, based on the following message:

[image]

But I couldn't see the usual messages saying that cuda library is successfully opened like that:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locallyI tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105]
```

When this occur the machine might get much more lower speed. The price of the computer is over $10000 with GTX1080TI, but it is slower than the $2000 one with GTX1080, which can see 'successfully opened CUDA library xxx' when running the same CNN. The version of software of both computer are the same. I have searched it in many places but couldn't find any solution. More details are as follow:

1. CUDA version: 9.0
2. CUDNN version: 7.0
3. Anaconda version: Anaconda3-5.2.0 with Python 3.6 inside
4. TensorFlow version: 1.9.0